# Add microdata to breadcrumbs - Some trouble with hooks

Tags: 7, theming, hooks, breadcrumbs

I'm trying to add microdata to the breadcrumbs. I found on the web [this fix](http://drupalbin.com/19863) which I tried to include to my own SEO module like this:

```
function mymod_page_alter(&$variables) {
    if (!isset($variables['breadcrumb'])) {
        $variables['breadcrumb'] = theme('my_microdata', array('breadcrumb' => drupal_get_breadcrumb()));
    }
}
function mymod_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'my_microdata' => array(
     'variables' => array('breadcrumb' =>array()),
    ),
  );
}
function mymod_menu_breadcrumb_alter(&$active_trail, $item){
  foreach($active_trail as $id=>$active_trail_item){
    $active_trail[$id]['localized_options']['attributes']['itemprop'][]="url";
  }
}
function theme_my_microdata($variables){
 $breadcrumb=$variables['breadcrumb'];
print_r(debug_backtrace());
 $output="*+*+*+*+*";
  if (!empty($breadcrumb)) {
    // Provide a navigational heading to give context for breadcrumb links to
    // screen-reader users. Make the heading invisible with .element-invisible.
    $output = '<h2 class="element-invisible">' . t('You are here') . '</h2>';
    $output .= '<div class="breadcrumb">';
    $separator="";
    foreach($breadcrumb as $breadcrumb_item){
      $output.='<span typeof="datav:Breadcrumb">'.$separator.$breadcrumb_item."</span>";
      $separator="»";
    }
    $output .='</div>';
  }

    return $output."xXxXxXx";
}
```

So far I checked that all this code is executed. But this theming is not applied on my page. Why does my code not work? Could this been related with the module `breadcrumb`? I know that this output will be garbage but I cannot see the result.

If I guess right than is the output created by *theme.inc* line 1682ff `theme_breadcrumb(...)`instead of my code. How can I change that?

---

I just found the [theme_breadcrumbs](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_breadcrumb/7) there is shown in their solution this line:

```
function YOURTHEME_breadcrumb($variables) {
```

Well can *YOURTHEME* my module name or have I to build a theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation of [hook_page_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_page_alter/7) doesn't work because the parameter passed to the hook (`$page`) doesn't contain `$page['breadcrumb']`.

I used the following code to verify the content of the parameter passed as argument.

```
$path = 'node/14';

if ($router_item = menu_get_item($path)) {
  if ($router_item['access']) {
    if ($router_item['include_file']) {
      require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/' . $router_item['include_file'];
    }
    $page_callback_result = call_user_func_array($router_item['page_callback'], $router_item['page_arguments']);
  }
}

$main_content_display = &drupal_static('system_main_content_added', FALSE);

if (is_string($page_callback_result) || (is_array($page_callback_result) && (!isset($page_callback_result['#type']) || ($page_callback_result['#type'] != 'page')))) {
  drupal_set_page_content($page_callback_result);
  $page_callback_result = element_info('page');
}

foreach (module_implements('page_build') as $module) {
  $function = $module . '_page_build';
  $function($page_callback_result);
}

drupal_alter('page', $page_callback_result);

if (!$main_content_display) {
  $page_callback_result['content']['system_main'] = drupal_set_page_content();
}

dsm($page_callback_result);
```

"node/14" is the path for an "Article" node I have on my test site.
The code has been created looking at the code of different Drupal functions: [drupal_deliver_html_page()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_deliver_html_page/7), [drupal_deliver_page()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_deliver_page/7), and [menu_execute_active_handler()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_execute_active_handler/7). It requires the Devel module, as it uses one of its functions.

This is the output given by `dsm()`.

[image: screenshot]

You can override the theme function used for the breadcrumb, implementing [hook_theme_registry_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme_registry_alter/7).

```
function mymodule_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  if (isset($theme_registry['breadcrumb'])) {
    $theme_registry['breadcrumb']['function'] = 'theme_mymodule_breadcrumb';
  }
}
```

`theme_mymodule_breadcrumb()` is the function that replaces [theme_breadcrumb()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_breadcrumb/7), and it gets the same parameters.

> `$variables`: An associative array containing:
>
> - breadcrumb: An array containing the breadcrumb links.

The theme function should be overridden if you want to alter its output. If you want to alter the value of the variables passed to `theme_breadcrumb()`, with Drupal 7 you can implement a preprocess function.

```
function mymodule_preprocess_breadcrumb(&$variables) {
  // Your code.
}
```

Comment: Well this answer is really great! That works. How do you learned that? Do you have some good ressources except drupal.org?

Comment: I read all I know about Drupal on Drupal.org (including Drupal.org API). The answers to questions here helps too, though.